# iTunes Connect - unable to submit app for review, localized language issue

Tags: ios, localization, app-store-connect

I am trying to **Submit for Review** a new version of an app I haven't updated for a couple years, but it says there are errors on the page. I corrected some errors and have only one remaining.

It is having an issue with my selected language, which is **English (U.S.)**.

All of the xibs are localized as English, but have no other localization beyond that.

In iTunes Connect, my app is in **Prepare for Submission** status with a red circle and an exclamation point next to English (U.S.) in the Version Information section. English (U.S.) is selected as the Primary.

I am unsure what to do to correct this issue, or exactly what the issue is. My understanding is if there is no localization for what is currently selected on the device, it will use the primary, which is English. Do I need to remove the English localization from all my xib files since it really is just a single xib regardless of what localization the device is set for?

Didn't have any issue with this when I initially released the app, so not sure what to do now. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After finally getting some helpful feedback from Apple, I have solved my problem.

The issue had to do with the **App Preview** and **Screenshot** images I had uploaded for the app.

I had not provided images for the **4.7-Inch Display** so I went into the **Media Manager** and selected the check box to Use **5.5-Inch Display**.

Did that and I was then able to submit the app. Could have also uploaded specific images for that size as well, and maybe I will later, but the images seem to have been the problem and not really a localization issue after all (although you can have different images for different localizations, but I only have a single primary localization).

I am now in a **Waiting For Review** status.